# Como averiguar la altura de la barra de titulos del frame

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe

tengo un problema con una aplicación, que se debe ejecutar en distintos sistemas operativos.
La aplicación tiene una ventana principal de tamaño fijo, el problema es que si la ejecuto en un SO distinto de Kubuntu, que es donde realicé la misma, la altura total del frame varia, el caso más extremo (probé con Windows 10, y Linux Mint 20), es en windows, el último botón de la aplicación, queda cortado a la mitad.
Entiendo que el problema esta en el alto de la barra de títulos, yo le asigné un valor que en Kubuntu funciona, pero no en otros SO, en definitiva, la pregunta es como obtengo la altura de la barra de títulos?, desde ya muchas gracias.

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Gui extends JFrame {
   
   public Gui() {       
      new JFrame();
      setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      setBounds( 10, 10, 200, 100 );
      setVisible( true );
      setLayout( null );
      JPanel pan = new JPanel();
      pan.setBackground( Color.red );  
      
      Insets screenInsets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets( getGraphicsConfiguration() );
      double altoBarra = screenInsets.top;
   }
    
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      Gui gui = new Gui();          
   }
}
```

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve], en tu caso ayudarian algunas capturas, el codigo de tu aplicacion, si quieres que funcione en retina display, etc

Comment: @RuslanLópez, he agregado una pequeña parte de la clase, no es que sirva para algo, ahora la pregunta sigue siendo, hay alguna forma de pedirle al sistema la altura de la barra de titulos?.

Comment: Prueba con el método [getInsets()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getInsets\(\)).

Comment: Hola @Sal, probé Insets a = getInsets();  int aa = a.top; pero me devuelve siempre cero, igual gracias por responder!!!

Comment: Tienes que llamarlo después de hacerlo visible.

Comment: y del codigo que pusiste que no compila... que parte se supone que es la barra de titulos? Que fuente usas? Ya intentaste sacar las propiedades de la fuente con su FontMetrics?

Comment: Hola @Sal, gracias por tu invalorable ayuda, finalmente usando Insets screenInsets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets( getGraphicsConfiguration() );
      screenInsets = getInsets();
      double altoBarra = screenInsets.top; me ha funcionado, podrías escrrbirlo como respuesta, así la marco como aceptada?... mil gracias

Comment: @RuslanLópez, la barra de titulos, es esa pequeña barra que tienen la mayoria de las aplicaciones, en la que va el titulo del frame, la misma que quitas si pones frame.setUndecorated( true ). Te sugiero leer como elaboro una buena pregunta, donde dice **No todas las preguntas se benefician del código incluido. Pero si tu problema está en el código que haz escrito, deberías incluir una parte**.